# Android: Access view objects outside of the activity

Tags: android, oop, coding-style, dry, findviewbyid

Please correct me if my OOP application is incorrect.  I have a custom Android class at `/src/myworkspace/MyObject.java` that does not extend anything.

```
public class MyObject {
  ...

  public void methodOne() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Within the main activity, `MyObject.methodOne()` is called.
How would I manipulate view objects in methodOne?
For example somthing similar to

```
mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_one);
mButton.setOnClickListener(mButtonListener);
```

The methods of MyObject are reused in many activities.  If this approach is incorrect, where should the repeatable code be stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest MyObject receive a view as a parameter:

```
public class MyObject {
...
  public void methodOne(Button button) {
   ...
  }
}
```

The just call it this way from your activity:

```
... activity code ....
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_one);
obj.methodOne(button);
.... more activity code.
```

You can use other approaches too :

Bind MyObject to activity in the constructor :

```
MyObject(Activity owner) {
   .. assign activity to member
}
```

Use Object as a nested inner class.

```
 Activity
   class MyObject {
```

Each has it's merits or gotchyas, I personally would stick with passing a view by parameter, it is the most loosly coupled, and IMO the simplest and least error prone.